# Chromatic number of certain graphs with high maximum degree

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, graph-colorings, cayley-graphs

Let $G$ be the graph of even order $n$ and size $\ge\frac{n^2}{4}$ which is a Cayley graph on a nilpotent group but not complete. Can the chromatic number of this graph be determined in polynomial time?

I suspect such a graph would have chromatic number less than or equal to $\frac{n}{2}$ if the generating set does not have order $2$ elements, because we would always find two unique elements non-adjacent to each other. Is this right? Or are there counterexamples?

Comment: The second claim is false: consider a complete n-partite graph with each partite having size 3.

Comment: @Bullet51 But, can the $n-$ partite graph be written as a cayley graph of a nilpotent group with generating set missing the elements of order $2$?

Comment: One can take a circulant graph: The vertices are from $\mathbb{Z}_{6n}$. Connect every pair $a,b$ unless $a-b \in \{0,2n,3n,4n\}$.

Comment: @Bullet51 but, the size of such a graph is $6n^2$ which is less than the required $\frac{(6n)^2}{4}=9n^2$ as I first proposed right?

Comment: No, the size is nearly $18n^2$ as there are few unconnected pairs..

Comment: @Bullet51My hypothesis is corrected now in the question. Edited now.

Comment: @Bullet51 got the size, its just $\frac{(6n)(6n-3)}{2}=18n^2-6n$ which of the order $18n^2$

Comment: If $G$ has even order $n$, then it has an element of order $2$ and, by hypothesis, this element is not in the generating set. This element induces a perfect matching in the complement of the graph. Therefore the original graph can be properly coloured with $n/2$ colours (colouring matched vertices with one colour).

The assumption of being non-complete is redundant, while the assumptions of nilpotency and size are irrelevant.

This could be an (easy) exercise after one first learns of Cayley graphs and is not research level.

Comment: @verret but my first question of whether there exists a polynomial time algorithm for computing the chromatic number of the cayley graph on a nilpotent group with order $n$ and size $\frac{n^2}{4}$ is, I hope non-trivial

Comment: why the downvote?